# Term-Driven Page with Friendy URL doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, term-store, cross-site-publishing

We are using Term-Driven Page with Friendy URL in terms store, one terms set is working another isn't. I checked the navigation and term-driven pages tabs and didn't see any different setting.

How can I troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Self answering questions; just wait for a while then it's working properly!